# How can I switch a production rails app (passenger/nginx/capistrano) to use RVM on Ubuntu?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, rvm, capistrano, passenger

I have a production app using passenger, nginx, and capistrano. I set it up without RVM (running ruby installed directly to the OS on Ubuntu without a version manager), but would like to switch over to using RVM so that I can upgrade ruby when I need to.

What steps do I need to take to install RVM and configure passenger/nginx/capistrano to use it?

The key here is that I already have the server running, and the downtime needs to be minimal / overnight since the app is being used in a production setting every day. I can't afford to mess up and have the app down for too long.

My best guess is that I'm going to need to modify my nginx config (sudo nano /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf) - and edit these lines: (?)

```
http {
    passenger_root /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.19;
    passenger_ruby /usr/local/bin/ruby;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow instruction on [rvm.io](http://rvm.io/rvm/install) to install `rvm`. However, you are strongly advised not to use it in production. A production setup should follow KISS principle. Every additional piece of software you install, will add a little bit of complexity to the setup. Given that all `rvm` does is to provide a set of handy commands to install ruby and change `PATH` variable, it is **not** an essential tool on production setup.

If all you need is ability to install new versions of ruby without messing things up, use [ruby-install](https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install). This makes it easy to install ruby, but will not manipulate environment settings (such as `PATH`).

As you mentioned above, you are right, you should just change the pointer to ruby executable in nginx configuration to switch ruby version. In production mode, this does not stop/interrupt your running rails application until you restart nginx. So it is safe to install a new version of ruby in another folder (such as `/usr/local/rubies/ruby-193-p448/`  or `/usr/local/rubies/ruby-200-p0/`), change `passenger_ruby` in nginx settings to point to the new ruby, then restart nginx.

Also note that from [Passenger 4.0.x](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#_configuring_phusion_passenger) onwards, you can use multiple versions of ruby with a single nginx/passenger combination, one to run passenger and another to your rails application using the `passenger_ruby` directive in `http` block and/or `server` block of `nginx` configuration.

Comment: This could probably work, but I'm pretty sure you got the downvote because RVM or rbenv are commonly used in production environments. I've already had a trusted Rails developer advise me to move over to RVM sooner than later, especially in efforts to be able to easily upgrade and downgrade ruby versions in the future if I need to.

Comment: That being said - I think you make a very good point. I might follow through with your advice. I'll let you know how it goes or what path I take.

Comment: Wayne Seguin himself has said he built `rvm` for production use. But that was before `rvm` became what it is today. There might be use cases for that. But ask any devops who has been handling production system. Lesser is better. If at all you want a convenience tool, there are better options - `rvm` is unnecessarily complex for  production use. I would choose `chruby` or `ruby-install` if I have to use one of them. But thanks - you heard my point.